# What OS / GUI / program is used for the computer in the movie Eraser (1996)?

Tags: display-technology

When Lee Cullen (played by Vanessa Williams) sneakily goes into the "Vault" of Cyrez, a large weapons manufacturing corporation, to copy some confidential company data, as instructed by the FBI, she uses a computer, which displays this GUI:

[image]

[image]

Do we know what OS is this? Or is it a specific program created for the movie, or some other application? If somebody knows about this kindly let us know.

Comment: It's not enough to go an as an answer, but the shape and styling of the `begin` button in the top image kinda looks like a Mac OS button on the likes of a Macintosh Plus computer

Comment: It's not Mac, though there are similarities. The old black & white System 6, from 90 or so [looked like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqxdf.jpg), but by 95, System 7.5 [looked like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIdL4.png)

Comment: I suspect it's a made up OS, used to avoid paying royalties to any real OS manufacturer.  Worth noting that they don't need to make a *real* OS - they just need to make an animation that does what the script calls for while the camera is rolling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a real product; it is listed [on a French blog post](https://www.blup.fr/2004/08/29/leffaceur-copie-des-chiffres/) describing liberties taken with software in films; one of the features of the software in Eraser is that it shows the bytes being copied when you ask it to copy files. No real software does this.